# notifydatachanged() for WebView instead load whole WebView

Tags: android, webview

I want to reload only changed data such as new comments(if any), instead reloading whole WebView.
I can't use `loadUrl("url")` method because it is reloading complete webview. I tried different ways but, none of them worked. Is there any method like `notifyDataSetChanged()` or any other way to do this?

I'm using Javascript interface to show dialog with comment option on click of posts in webview. When user post any comment, i need to show that comment below that particular post with out reload webview again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in your Android code. You have to implement Ajax in your webpage to do it.